# Python scraper and saving data to file, I need it to include the <br> tag in the file

Tags: python, html, xml, scraper

Alright so this is my code for a webscraper I've build. Right now it scrapes everything that I've selected with soup. But when I view the source code of my page this data includes a `<br>` which is line break.

When I scrape and save everything to the file, this gets excluded which makes all the data in one line without the `<br>` tag. I want this `<br>` to be there after each data is written to the file as follows:

```
Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>
```

And not:

```
DataDataDataDataData
```

Is there anyway to currently modify my code? I think it's the `g = item.text.encode('utf-8')` that makes it remove the `<br>`. I would be happy if I could include the `<br>` in the code because then I can just [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6917168) it.

```
    try :
                t_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "blockrow restore"})
                for item in t_data:
                    f = open('test.txt' , 'w')
                    g = item.text.encode('utf-8')
                    f.write(g)
                    f.close 


            finally:
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post an abbreviated sample of the HTML you're scraping, showing the relationship between the `div`s you're searching for and the <br> tags within them?

Comment: In other news, it looks like your `for` loop might be overwriting "test.txt" on each iteration. You probably want to open it for [a]ppend instead of [w]rite.

Comment: <div class="blockrow restore">Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data
</div>

The output becomes: DataDataDataDataDataDataDataDataData
instead of: Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>Data<br>

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to capture the `<br>` newlines, you can just replace the `<br>` tag in the item with a new line character before parsing:

```
for br in item.find_all("br"):
    br.replace_with("\n")
```

If you actually want to preserve the internal HTML of the tag, you can just convert the BeautifulSoup item back to a string and print that:

```
g = unicode(item)
```

Comment: Thank you very much I did the replace loop and it worked! Thanks!